# sdl cross compile fail

Tags: ffmpeg, arm, sdl

I want to cross compile ffmpeg to arm with ffplay, which needs sdl. So, I have to cross compile sdl. 
  I download the latest sdl, and configure. 
  but there are some errors, like error: 'ULLONG_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function),
how to solve? 
  And how to cross compile sdl successfully?

Comment: What are the first errors? `ULLONG_MAX` should be declared in <limits.h>, so I suspect the configure step.

Comment: This is my configure step,./configure --prefix=/home/clinyong/ffmpeg/ --host=arm-linux --enable-shared cc=/opt/4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-gcc --disable-arts --disable-joystick --disable-video-x11 --disable-alsa --disable-video-dummy --disable-esd  Do you know the right configure step

Comment: apply this patch and try to build libsdl [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/oe-core/master/meta/recipes-graphics/libsdl/libsdl-1.2.15/configure_tweak.patch ]

Comment: @clinyong Did you solve it?

Comment: @ashwanthselvam Link not found!

Comment: This patch has been removed from yocto since it was redundant after excluding autoheader but if you need the patch use this link http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/108869/